# Create dummy table to join with existing table?

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
id | name  | pos_x  | pos_y
---------------------------
1    jack    2        0
2    bryan   7        1
3    andy    0        3
```

how can I make this table turning like this:

```
id | name  | position | value
-----------------------------
1    jack    pos_x        2
1    jack    pos_y        0
2    bryan   pos_x        7
2    bryan   pos_y        1
3    andy    pos_x        0
3    andy    pos_y        3
```

I turning my head upside down to make a query having result like this, but cant make it.
any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use UNION on two queries each producing have of your result:

```
(SELECT `id`, `name`, 'pos_x' AS `position`, `pos_x` AS `value` FROM myTable)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `id`, `name`, 'pos_y' AS `position`, `pos_y` AS `value` FROM myTable)
```